# Why don't I have Strunk and White?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, badges

I noticed on the election page that I don't have [Strunk and White](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/badges/12/strunk-white), but I would think I should have it.  My [user activity page](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/45/c-ross?tab=activity&sort=revisions) shows that I've done *162* revisions, while the badge only requires 80 edits.  Why don't I have the badge?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to edit separate posts, not make 80 individual edits.  If you've more than doubled up your edits you may need to go a bit farther.

You can check your current progress by viewing the [Review page](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/review/).  Your progress towards your next edit badge is in the middle/lower of the right hand column.

The full requirements can be found on [meta.stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions)

- Perform a total of 80 edits between questions and answers
- Edits on deleted posts do not count
- Edits to your own posts do not count
- Edits to CW posts do count
- Edits that consist only of tag changes do not count
- Tag wiki edits do count
- Edits you suggest before gaining full edit privileges do count, once approved
- Each edited post counts only once, regardless of how many additional edits you may submit

Answer (score 2):

Have you "edited 80 posts," though?

Based on a quick glance at your revisions, you've made multiple revisions to some posts (not that there's anything wrong with that ;) ), so it's possible that 162 revisions is actually only spread over (for example) 70 individual posts.

I have 228 revisions on Board and Card Games, [per the review page](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/review/), I've only modified 75 separate posts.